# How to check if coordinates valid or invalid without using google api?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, maps

Is there a way to check if map coordinates valid or invalid? I have a scenario that my latitude and longitude entered might got swapped so I have to check if its existing in globe coordinates. So far I need to use API just to check whether if its a valid coordinates or not.

On this example, this origin could not find in google map. I can't find any question similar similar to this.

```
const origin = {
        latitude:   106.892775, //parseFloat(res.pickuplat),
        longitude:  -6.163772 //parseFloat(res.pickuplong),
      };

try{
        const address = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(origin)
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
```

Comment: Check `status == 'OK'` `$geo = json_decode($geo, true); if ($geo['status'] == 'OK') { // info returned without error }`

Comment: `$geo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false&key='.APIKEY);`

Comment: *I have a scenario that my latitude and longitude entered might got swapped so I have to check if its existing in globe coordinates.* - so what if my latitude is `46` and longitude `4`? How could you tell which is which? `46, 4` and `4, 46` are both valid coordinates.

Comment: @dalelandry This is 1) Not free and 2) Not reliable for all earth coordinates. Try geocoding `88, 0`. These are valid earth coordinates but will trigger a Geocoder error (not status "OK" as you mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to verify our coordinate is to check

`latitude` must be a value between -90 and 90

and `longitude` must be between -180 and 180

Comment: This is correct but Google uses the World Geodetic System WGS84 standard for their maps and therefore a latitude of 90 or -90 would be off the map.